# Examples of state space models where the filtering problem can be solved analytically

Tags: time-series, bayesian, hidden-markov-model, kalman-filter, state-space-models

## Background

A discrete-time, Markovian state space model takes the form
\begin{align}
\mathbf{y}_t&\sim p(\mathbf{y}_t\,|\,\mathbf{s}_t,\,\boldsymbol{\theta})\\
\mathbf{s}_t&\sim p(\mathbf{s}_t\,|\,\mathbf{s}_{t-1},\,\boldsymbol{\theta})\\
\mathbf{s}_0&\sim p(\mathbf{s}_0\,|\,\boldsymbol{\theta}),
\end{align}
where the $\mathbf{y}_t$ are observable, the $\mathbf{s}_t$ are latent, and $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ collects all of the parameters (assumed known) that govern the system.

To solve the [filtering problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filtering_problem_(stochastic_processes)), we want to recursively compute the marginal posteriors
$$p(\mathbf{s}_t\,|\,\mathbf{y}_{1:t},\,\boldsymbol{\theta}) = \frac{p(\mathbf{y}_t\,|\,\mathbf{s}_t,\,\boldsymbol{\theta})p(\mathbf{s}_t\,|\,\mathbf{y}_{1:t-1},\,\boldsymbol{\theta})}{p(\mathbf{y}_t\,|\,\mathbf{y}_{1:t-1},\,\boldsymbol{\theta})}$$
known as the *filtering distributions*. This requires that we be able to compute the predictive distributions
\begin{align}
p(\mathbf{s}_t\,|\,\mathbf{y}_{1:t-1},\,\boldsymbol{\theta})&=\int p(\mathbf{s}_t\,|\,\mathbf{s}_{t-1},\,\mathbf{y}_{1:t-1},\,\boldsymbol{\theta})p(\mathbf{s}_{t-1}\,|\,\mathbf{y}_{1:t-1},\,\boldsymbol{\theta}) \,\textrm{d}\mathbf{s}_{t-1} \\
p(\mathbf{y}_t\,|\,\mathbf{y}_{1:t-1},\,\boldsymbol{\theta})&=\int p(\mathbf{y}_t\,|\,\mathbf{s}_t,\,\boldsymbol{\theta})p(\mathbf{s}_t\,|\,\mathbf{y}_{1:t-1},\,\boldsymbol{\theta}) \,\textrm{d}\mathbf{s}_{t}.
\end{align}
There is work that I don't understand on [necessary](https://doi.org/10.1016/0167-6911(90)90083-7) and [sufficient](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bj/1080222084) conditions for when these integrals are tractable, but I don't think we have a single set of necessary *and* sufficient conditions that lock the problem down (please correct me if I'm wrong!).

## Examples

Closed-form solutions are known in two famous examples.

#### Hidden Markov Model

In this model,

\begin{align}
\mathbf{y}_t&\sim p(\mathbf{y}_t\,|\,s_t,\,\boldsymbol{\phi})\\
s_t&\sim \text{Categorical}(\mathbf{p}_{s_{t-1}})\\
s_0&\sim \text{Categorical}(\mathbf{p}_0),
\end{align}
where $\boldsymbol{\theta} = \left\{\boldsymbol{\phi},\,\{\mathbf{p}_j\}_{j=0}^M\right\}$. So the measurement distribution can be whatever, and the univariate latent state follows a discrete-state Markov chain. In this case, the integrals become finite sums.

#### Linear, Gaussian System

In this model,

\begin{align}
\mathbf{y}_t&=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{s}_t + \mathbf{b}+\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}_t, &&\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}_t\sim N(\mathbf{0},\,\mathbf{\Sigma})\\
\mathbf{s}_t&=\mathbf{C}\mathbf{s}_{t-1} + \mathbf{d}+\boldsymbol{\eta}_t, &&\boldsymbol{\eta}_t\sim N(\mathbf{0},\,\mathbf{\Omega})\\
\mathbf{s}_0&\sim N(\bar{\mathbf{s}}_{0},\,\mathbf{P}_0),
\end{align}
where $\boldsymbol{\theta}=\{\mathbf{A},\,\mathbf{b},\,\boldsymbol{\Sigma},\,\mathbf{C},\,\mathbf{d},\,\boldsymbol{\Omega},\,\bar{\mathbf{s}}_{0},\,\mathbf{P}_0\}$. In this case, all of the predictive and filtering distributions are Gaussian, and their moments can be computed using the [Kalman filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter).

#### Others

In addition to these, we have analytical solutions for

- The record prediction model from [Smith and Miller (1986 JRSSB)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2345640);
- The Matrix-Beta stochastic volatility model from [Uhlig (1997 Econometrica)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2171813);
- The class of exponential family state space models from [Vidoni (1999 JRSSB)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2680746).

## Question

What are other examples of state space models where the filtering problem can be solved analytically? I ask with the hope of collecting in one place a running list of examples.

Answer (score 3):

For a list of examples, in the thesis *Bayesian state estimation in partially observable Markov processes* ([available here](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-01705284/document)), the author explores many different models summed up in Figure 1 (in French) in page 12.

[image: models]

Then in page 25 of the document, he claims, with appropriate references, that (C6) (C5) (D2) (D1) (H2) are models where the filtering problem can always be solved exactly.